# how to get overall F statistic and p value for lmer model?

Tags: r, regression, lme4-nlme

When you run lm and then summary, you get an R2, F statistic, and *P* value for the overall model. How do you get this (particularly the overall *P* Value) when you use mixed models?

[image]

```
library(lme4)
library(lmerTest)
library(car)
data(mtcars)
m <- lm(mpg ~ wt + cyl, data = mtcars)
summary(m)
mm <- lmer(mpg ~ wt + cyl + (1|hp), data = mtcars)
summary(mm)
```

Comment: You can use the `anova()` function to compare your model to a null model.  See: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24019807/how-to-compare-a-model-with-no-random-effects-to-a-model-with-a-random-effect-us](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24019807/how-to-compare-a-model-with-no-random-effects-to-a-model-with-a-random-effect-us)

Comment: Hello - that gives a Chi-square by default but I need an F-statistic. Thanks for your help